# in C#, how can I get the HTML content of a website before displaying it?

Tags: c#, html, browser, web

I have a web browser project in C#, I am thinking such system; when user writes the url then clicks "go" button, my browser get content of written web site ( **it shouldn't visit that page, I mean it shouldn't display anything**), then I want look for a specific "keyword" for ex; "violence", if there exists, I can navigate that browser to a local page that has a warning. Shortly, in C#, How can I get content of a web site **before visiting**?...

Sorry for my english, 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't do that in C# or any other language. It is like asking to get the contents of a file without reading it. What you seem to want is to have a proxy server that will redirect on certain inspected content.

Comment: @Oded If I read this right, it's more like asking to get the contents of a file without opening them in a text editor.

Comment: @delnan - I find the question to be unclear. If the OP wants to redirect the browser to a different page if some content exists on the page the browser is trying to access, there are existing solutions for that - using a proxy.

Comment: Problem solved Guys.. Thanks a lot to all of you, I haven't tried Hall72215's, and Jim O'Neil's solution, They're probably correct, but Giesi's solution solved my problem. But be sure that your url starts with "http://"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use WebRequest and WebResponse to load a site:

example:

```
string GetPageSource (string url)
{
HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
webrequest.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
string responseHtml;
using (StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    responseHtml = responseStream.ReadToEnd().Trim();
}

return responseHtml;
}
```

After that you can check the responseHtml for some Keywords... for example with RegEx.

Comment: first thank you so much, My code is like that;

                String url= urlComboBox.Text;
                String html = GetPageSource(url);

                if (html.Contains("violence")) 
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Here is forbidden", "Opps!!!");
                    getCurrentBrowser().Navigate(@"W:\yasak.html");
                }
                else
                {
                    getCurrentBrowser().Navigate(urlComboBox.Text);
                }

But in first line of your method.. It gives UriException says "Unknown URI format" in ...Create(url);

Comment: Your code worked! Thank you so much @Giesi , I just forget to add "http://" tag to front of url. Then It worked well.. Big thanks for you... :)

Comment: No Problem ... that is why we are here ;)

Answer (score 3):

[System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
string url = "http://www.google.com";
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
string html = wc.DownloadString(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an HTTP request (via [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) to the site) and parse the results looking for the various keywords.  Then you can make the decision whether or not to visibly 'navigate' the user there.

There's an [HTTP client sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HttpClient-sample-55700664) on Dev Center that may help.

Comment: just realized I was answering this in the context of Windows Store apps, but much still applies in the broader case